# Neither Web.config nor .htaccess effecting website

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess, web-config, iis-6

I'm working on setting up some rewrites for a client whose site I've never worked on. The goal is simple, but for some reason the server seems to be ignoring .htaccess files and Web.config files! I tried both just in case, but the server is running Microsoft-IIS/6.0 and is powered by PleskWin, ASP.NET, and PHP/5.2.17. The site is running Wordpress and all of the code is written in PHP. At the very least, the Web.config file should break the website, but it has absolutely no affect. Both files are in the root directory "httpdocs" which is the same directory as the index.php file.

Here is my Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|ttf|eot" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="admin.php" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="index.php" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

And my .htaccess (just in case)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^google.html$ http://www.google.com/ [R=301]
```

Comment: Microsoft-IIS don't support .htaccess as far as I know

Comment: Right. Which is why I wrote "just in case". It's definitely the Web.config file I need to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your redirects are not working because the `system.webServer` element is not supported in IIS 6.0, so any info you specify in that section will not be used (see here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver).

If you want to do redirects in IIS 6.0, then you may have to install a separate ISAPI filter. These questions have more information:

[where to write URL rewrite rule in IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309087/where-to-write-url-rewrite-rule-in-iis-6)
https://serverfault.com/questions/1408/how-can-i-rewrite-urls-ala-mod-rewrite-for-free-in-iis-6

Also, it's worth mentioning to make sure that a web application set up for this site in IIS. If the files are just in a virtual directory with no application created, then ASP.NET won't be used to run the website. In rereading your question, it certainly seems as if this was done already, but I thought I'd mention it just in case. The documentation for how to do that can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1d1c9a73-b4c5-4cfb-ad69-b77fa2e17e19.mspx?mfr=true