# to create vanity URL for existing URL for asp project in IIS 6, by not installing anything

Tags: asp-classic, web-config, iis-6, global-asax

I am new to .net ecosystem and to my project. I have been assigned a task to create Vanity URLs as follows.

The existing URL is:

> www.example.com.in/Public/Basic-Page.html
>   Vanity URL: example.com.in/BasicPage

Both the links have to work at the end,pointing to existing URL . The entire project is in asp, IIS 6. 
I understand we can make changes in web.config, global.asax to achieve this. But what exactly should I code and where exactly should I put this changes.
or
Can I use  in web.config to achieve this if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11309639/858905), there's no URL rewriting built in to IIS6, but you can use [Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://iirf.codeplex.com).

Another option is to use custom error pages to direct all 404 requests to a ASP page where you then `Server.Transfer` to the appropriate page. You can do this by modifying the web.config file...

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.asp" />
    </customErrors>
    ....
</system.web>
```

Then you can look at `Request.QueryString` to determine what page was requested, and use `Server.Transfer` to redirect to the correct page. Using `Server.Transfer` will be better than a `response.Redirect` for SEO.

There's also other ways of doing this using ASP.NET.

Comment: I'm not sure that web.config setting will work on IIS6, I think you may need to open a remote desktop connection and set a custom 404 page through IIS manager.  There are third party solutions like the Ionics Isapi module, or the Helicontech one (which isn't free), however IIS6 is associated with Windows 2003, for which Microsoft ended support last year, so if the site hasn't been migrated to IIS7 or 8 yet maybe you should suggest that it needs to be.  With IIS7 and above you can use the URL rewrite module.

Comment: Thanks @John. Our project already have a <customErrors>, where 404 errors are handled.  And IIS 7 or 8 migration wont happen anytime soon.As project is hugh and management chain is long. Same is the case for 3rd party solutions. So is there anyway to proceed by making changes to global.asax,

Comment: I am using the following code in global.asax,

'code'
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
<script runat="server">
 Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim URL_path As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path
        If URL_path.Contains("/BasicPage") Then
Context.RewritePath(URL_path.Replace("/BasicPage", "/Public/Basic-Page.html"))
        End If
End Sub
</script>

But this doenst have any effect,
I have also tried using Application_BeginRequest instead of  Application_Start.  I dont know if Application_BeginRequest is supported in VB.

Comment: In case you're confused there are two people with the username "John" who answer Classic ASP questions.  To make it even more confusing we're both on about the same number of points.  If a server migration and third party components aren't an option then using a custom 404 page is all you have left.  I've never tried it, This link tells you how to set it up - http://www.quickersite.com/ufl.  I think the other John wrote a blog about what to put in the 404 page itself, although I can't find the link. Security issues may just persuade your managers that a server migration is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, other @John, heres my (crappy old) blog post: http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/19/url-rewriting-in-asp/. I am pretty sure you can do this in IIS6 too. RakeshSiri, you could change your existing custom errors element in web.config to point to an error handling page, and still use your existing custom error page when the error handling page doesn't find a URL it knows.

Comment: And @John, this is not really the place, but to avoid confusion I have changed my display name to "johna" (I have even been confused myself sometimes as to which John I am).